# How best to deal with HTTP response in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using ActiveModel instead of ActiveRecord. And my model is:

```
class User
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, 
    :format => 
    { 
        :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
    }
    validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true,
    :length =>
    {
        :within => 6..40
    }

    attr_accessor :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    def initialize(attributes = {})
        @name  = attributes[:name]
        @email = attributes[:email]
        @password = attributes[:password]
        @password_confirmation = attributes[:password_confirmation]
    end

    def persisted?
        false
    end

    def save
        # createUser calls RESTful HTTP server and gets back JSON in http response's body
    response = createUser(self.name, self.email, self.password)
    end
end
```

And in my users_controller.rb below when I try to process this response returned by save method above, it messes up my model's validations for password and password_confirmation.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    response = @user.save
    parsed_response_body = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
    # response body I have is {"ok":"ok message"} OR {"error":"error message"}
    message = parsed_response_body["error"]
    if @user.valid? && message.nil?
        flash[:success] = message
        redirect_to signup_path
    else
        @user.password = ""
        @user.password_confirmation = ""
        flash[:error] = message
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

And below is controller code that doesn't break the validations; where @user.save in this case is returning true.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.valid? && @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Done"
        redirect_to signup_path
    else
        @user.password = ""
        @user.password_confirmation = ""
        flash[:error] = "Not Done"
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

I'd be thankful if someone can help me with this..

Comment: What's your question, specifically?

Comment: @mark my question is that why is it that when I add code for handling response in my controller, it breaks User's password, and password_confirmation validations? Am I doing something wrong in handling the response?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to call `super` in `save` or it won't actually try to validate:

```
def save
    super

    # createUser calls RESTful HTTP server and gets back JSON in http response's body
    response = createUser(self.name, self.email, self.password)
end
```